# вставляет только первую строчку из json в mysql

Tags: python, mysql, json

````
data = a.json()
#print(data)
names = [item["nick"] for item in data["moderators"]]
discord_u = [item["user_id"] for item in data["moderators"]]
vk_m = [item["vk"] for item in data["moderators"]]
x = {
    'nick': names,
    'user_id': discord_u,
    'vk': vk_m
}
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="",
        user="",
        password="",
        database="",
        )
curs = mydb.cursor()
for i in range(len(names)):
        curs.execute('SELECT * FROM moderator WHERE id = id')
        sql = curs.fetchall()
        if len(sql)<15:
            sqlFormula = 'INSERT INTO moderator (id, coins, nick, warns, VK) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'
            values = (discord_u[i], 0, names[i], 0, vk_m[i])
            curs.execute(sqlFormula, values)
            mydb.commit()
        else:
            pass
    ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что у Вас не указан параметр `id` для сравнения.  Вместо этого Вы пишете `id = id`, что не имеет смысла. Вы можете исправить код, заменив строку

`curs.execute('SELECT * FROM moderator WHERE id = id')`

на

`curs.execute('SELECT * FROM moderator WHERE id = %s', (discord_u[i],))`

Это изменение позволит выбрать все строки таблицы `moderator`, где значение поля `id` совпадает с `discord_u[i]`.